# Caching - .NET Core equivalents of .NET Framework classes

Tags: .net, caching, .net-core

Looking to understand some of the changes in .NET Core vs .NET Framework and the area I'm looking at is caching. In Framework - in the `System.Runtime.Caching` namespace - there are the `CacheItem`(which represented an individual cache entry in the cache) and `CacheItemPolicy`(representing a set of eviction and expiration details for a specific cache entry) classes.

From my initial look at this these two classes appear not to have made it across to Core, but are there some (differently named) equivalents to them that I'm just not finding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CacheItem` and `CacheItemPolicy` are there in all versions - you may need the package from NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Caching/4.7.0

Comment: Hello Marc - many thanks for the speedy answer! It was my understanding that in Core you had to use the Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory package. The one that you've linked to appears to be Framework or am I completely wrong?

Comment: @noonand that package supports multiple TFMs, including .NET Standard 2.0, which means it is fine for .NET Core

Comment: Thanks for that - it was my understanding that I had to use Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory when dealing with Core. Every day's a learning day :-)

Comment: If anyone's reading this later and wondering what Marc means when he talks about supporting multiple TFMs here's the best explanation I've found about doing it: http://www.tamirdresher.com/blog/2017/04/05/Easily_supporting_multiple_target_frameworks_(TFMs)_with_VS2017_and_Nuget___IBlogger_-_Tamir_Dresher

Comment: @noonand that article is about writing a *library* that supports multiple TFMs; in your case, you're just the consumer, so you don't need that - all you need to do is: in [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Caching/), expand the "Dependencies" section, and see what it says - usually, you're looking for a netstandard2.something or netcoreapp3.something entry; in this case, there's a .netstandard2.0, so you're fine. The full "what can consume what" is a bit more complex, but: if all else fails: just try installing it - the tooling will tell you if it is wrong.